# Binding two controls to two sources same time

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying bind textbox to String variable same time I want to bind ComboBox to List.

```
<Window 
        x:Class="Assignment2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:validators="clr-namespace:Assignment2"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="109,103,0,0" Name="StringComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                <Binding Path="ListString" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus"></Binding>
            </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,51,250,0" Name="inputTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="154" LostFocus="inputTextBox_LostFocus">
            <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Name1" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <validators:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="This field Should not be empty"></validators:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <validators:OnlyCharacterValidation ErrorMessage="Only characters allowed"></validators:OnlyCharacterValidation>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind is:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string _name = "Default Value";
        public ObservableCollection<string> ListString;
        public string Name1
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            ListString = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            ListString.Add("AAA");
            ListString.Add("BBB");
            ListString.Add("CCC");
            ListString.Add("DDD");

            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) 
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private void inputTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("Name1");
        }

    }
}
```

I can't seem to bind Combobox and Textbox at the same time. I have tried many solutions to this. but either way only one of these works.
Is there any simple solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public string Name1
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }
```

Forgot `OnPropertyChanged("Name1");` ?

Also :

```
public ObservableCollection<string> ListString;
```

Your ListString should be a Property, not just a field :

```
public ObservableCollection<string> ListString { get; set; }
```

Finally, I don't see the reason for this :

```
private void inputTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  OnPropertyChanged("Name1");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your properties should call the `OnPropertyChanged` handler like this:

```
public string Name1
{
    get { return _name; }
    set
    {
        _name = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Name1"); 
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<string> listString = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public ObservableCollection<string> ListString
{
    get { return listString ; }
    set
    {
        listString = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ListString"); 
    }
}
```

Please look carefully at the example in the [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) page on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

Try change to this.

```
public string Name1
{
    get { return _name; }
    set
    {
        _name = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Name1");
    }
}
```